# Scale down overlapping image with Foundation

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

My css skills are limited so I hope someone can help me with this...

I am using Foundation and I have 2 divs with 2 images.The left div overlaps the right div. When the browser is resized, the left image loses it's original position.

This is what [the site looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kr3J3.jpg) when the browser is expanded.

And this is what happens when [I resize the browser.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ikzg5.jpg)

This is the code that I currently have on the left image (wireframe image)

```
.wireframe-img {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-top: 50px;
    max-width: 815px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-left: 50px;
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 1

}
```

And the image on the right (ipad) is in a div with this code:

```
.small-7 {
    position: relative;
    width: 58.3333%;
}
.column, .columns {
    float: left;
    padding-left: 0.9375em;
    padding-right: 0.9375em;
}
.right {
    float: right !important;
}
```

I basically want the "wireframe" image to scale down and not lose it's original position when the browser is resized.

Comment: This may have to do with the media queries and/or breakpoints in your site. If you do have breakpoints set, then you'll need to update your CSS to accommodate the new position(s) at that breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than overlapping the image, it's better in your case to just have two separate images next to each other that match up pixel perfect.

Then just have one image like this:
http://puu.sh/6UTqY.jpg
and the other like this:
http://puu.sh/6UTqa.jpg (Roughly)

Unless there's another reason as to why you're keeping that images separate and trying to overlap them?

Comment: I thought about doing that but first thing that comes to my mind is how would I keep the 2 images parallel to each other when the site is viewed from a mobile device for example. Won't something like this happen when I scale down the browser? http://imgur.com/wFvRbng

Comment: I guess I can place both images in one div and use inline-block;

Comment: Yes you can do that and have a percentage width also so the images decrease in size together making sure that the second image won't wrap around again.